# How do you get your WP7 app to show up in the Games Hub?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I've made a simple game for WP7 but apparently simply using the XNA template isn't enough to get your game to show up in the games hub.  What code do I need to make that happen?

Also, can I get games made in silverlight to show up in the Games Hub as well? If so, how do I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to edit the **WMAppManifest.xml** file (in *Properties* [C#] or *My Project* [VB.NET]) to set `Genre="apps.normal"` (in the `<App>` element) to `Genre="apps.games"`. This will work for both XNA and Silverlight apps. See [Application Manifest File for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769509%28VS.92%29.aspx#BKMK_Application) for more details.

Give it a try and side-load it to your phone for testing - it's pretty cool to see it show up in the Games Hub.

Comment: That didn't seem to work.  I updated my question to include my <APP> element. Can you spot anything wrong with it? Thanks

Comment: Oops, left out the 's' in games :)

Comment: Ugh, I just saw that typo too. `Genre="apps.games"` is the right way to do it.