# Non-XNA game into Games?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is it possible to make a normal WP7 app as a game (simple flashcards) and have it be placed into games hub? Or is it necessary that all games are created in XNA, no matter they do or don't have animations?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853760/how-do-you-get-your-wp7-app-to-show-up-in-the-games-hub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can submit a non-XNA game to the Games hub (Category: Game).

Probably more than 1/2 the games in the Games category are based on Silverlight.

Sources: We have a Silverlight game in the games hub. :)